# Отправка таблицы в письме

Tags: php, html

Здравствуйте! Есть текст сообщения `$message` и таблица `$table`

```
$table="

<table class='table table-hover object_table'>

 <thead>
             <tr>
                <th width='50'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-bookmark'></i> №</th>
                <th><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip'></i> Название</th>
                <th>Артикул</th>
                <th>Цена</th>
                <th>Кол-во</th>
            </tr>
 </thead>

 <tbody>".
            $i = 0;
            $n = 0;
            $total = 0;

            foreach (get_idobject($connect, $arr_object_count) as $ps):$i++;
                $total += $ps['price'] * $arr_object_count[$n][1]; ?>
                <tr>
                    <td>$i;</td>
                    <td><?= $ps['name']; ?></td>
                    <td><?= $ps['article']; ?></td>
                    <td><?= $ps['price'] * $arr_object_count[$n][1]; ?> р.</td>
                    <td align="center"><?= $arr_object_count[$n][1]; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php $n++; endforeach; ?>
 <tr>
    <td align="right" colspan="5">Общая сумма: <?= $total; ?> р.</td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>";
```

Отправляю таблицу вместе с текстом: 
`$message =$message. $table;`

`mail($userEmail, $subject, $message, $headers);`

На почту приходит только заголовки из таблицы(т.е. Артикул, Цена, Кол-во), а сами данные с этой таблицы не приходят. Я подозреваю что переменная `$table` как-то неправильно формируется. Надеюсь на вашу помощью

Comment: Так всё правильно. заголовок пишется в переменную, а остальное пишеться просто так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А если попробовать так?:

```
$i = 0;
$n = 0;
$total = 0;


//Подготовим тело
$tbody = "";
foreach (get_idobject($connect, $arr_object_count) as $ps) {
    $i++;
    $total += $ps['price'] * $arr_object_count[$n][1];
    $_tableRow .= "<tr>";
    $_tableRow .= "<td>$i</td>";
    $_tableRow .= "<td>".$ps['name']."</td>";
    $_tableRow .= "<td>".$ps['price'] * $arr_object_count[$n][1]."</td>";
    $_tableRow .= "<td align='center'>".$arr_object_count[$n][1]."</td>";
    $_tableRow .= "</tr>";
    $tbody .= $_tableRow;
    $n++; 
} 

//скомпонуем
$table = "<table class='table table-hover object_table'>
    <thead>
         <tr>
            <th width='50'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-bookmark'></i> №</th>
            <th><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip'></i> Название</th>
            <th>Артикул</th>
            <th>Цена</th>
            <th>Кол-во</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>".  $tbody . "
        <tr>
            <td align='right' colspan='5'>Общая сумма: $total р.</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>";
$message = $message . $table;       
mail($userEmail, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: спасибо! Я так и сделал. Забыл написать